# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException while implementing a shopping basket in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I have a problem with basket. How to resolve this kinds of problem to solve it?

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   pl.library.web.books.cdi.CartBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy cannot be
>   cast to java.util.List

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class CartBean implements Serializable {

    private BookLDM book;
    private int quantity;

    public CartBean(BookLDM byId, int i) {
        this.book = byId;
        this.quantity = i;
    }

    public BookLDM getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(BookLDM book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public CartBean() {}
}
```

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class BoxManager implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8267670504661589685L;

    @Inject
    private CartBean cart;
    @EJB
    private BookService bookService;

    public BoxManager() {}

    public CartBean getCart() {
        return cart;
    }

    public void addItem(final Long itemId) {

        if (cart == null) {
            List<CartBean> cart = new ArrayList<CartBean>();
            cart.add(new CartBean(this.bookService.getById(itemId), 1));
        } else {
            List<CartBean> cart = (List<CartBean>) getCart();
            int index = isExisting(itemId);
            if (index == -1) {
                cart.add(new CartBean(this.bookService.getById(itemId), 1));
            } else {
                int quantity = cart.get(index).getQuantity() + 1;
                cart.get(index).setQuantity(quantity);
            }
        }
    }

    private int isExisting(long id) {
        List<CartBean> cart = (List<CartBean>) getCart();

        for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
            if (cart.get(i).getBook().getId() == id) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe think about an `Object` and a collection of `Object` and you'll find the problem for sure

Comment: This is not a JSF specific problem. You should take a JSF pause, take a step back and spend a bit more time learning basic Java. Before diving into Java EE, you should among others be able to explain and solve `java.lang.*` exceptions from top of head, or at least be able to research them in the javadocs and tutorials.

Comment: i wrote similar code in spring and there i dont get such exception ...

Comment: It's also not Spring specific. You just made a basic Java mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well information is obvious. In this line `List<CartBean> cart = (List<CartBean>) getCart();` you are trying to cast `CartBean` into `List<CartBean>`. It cannot work. Do it the same way as you did couple of lines above and firstly create new `ArrayList<CartBean>` then create new object returned by `getCart()` method and finally add this object to your list.